# watch point in shared memory c++

Tags: c++, linux

I have two different processes running at the same time. The first one PZ_ONE is a Blackbox, and it is producing the data. The second one is my code, PZ_TWO and is consuming the data. For the communication I must use shared memory. Hier the question: is there any way to know when PZ_ONE has updated the shared memory segment? the thing is I’m using a Raspberry Pi and polling is not efficient. I need to program a “watch point” or an “Interrupt” so I will know when the process (PZ_ONE) writes in the shared memory segment and read the data just when the shared memory segment has been updated. I’m programming in c++

Comment: I think you need to provide your code to show what sort of shared memory you're using. Also - what is PZ_ONE - is it a third party application? Does it use any semaphores or other locks for access control that you might be able to use?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.